Sending Objects over AIDL via Parcelables
I have a server and client app, and I am just trying to send an object called Component over AIDL from server to client.
Here is the AIDL interface aidlinterface.aidl:
// aidlInterface.aidl
package com.example.aidl_service;
import com.example.aidl_service.Component;

 interface aidlInterface {
     double[] getRandomLatLong(); // Existing method to get random location
     void setNewLatLong(double lat, double lon); // New method to send modified location

     // New methods for Component object
     Component getComponent(); // Fetches the Component object
     void setComponent(in Component component); // Sets the Component object
 }


The Component.aidl:
// Component.aidl
package com.example.aidl_service;
parcelable Component;

Server App Code
The java component class implemented as a parcelabel Component.java in the server app:
package com.example.aidl_service;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

public class Component implements Parcelable {
    private String name;
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;

    public Component(String name, double latitude, double longitude) {
        this.name = name;
        this.latitude = latitude;
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }

    protected Component(Parcel in) {
        name = in.readString();
        latitude = in.readDouble();
        longitude = in.readDouble();
    }

    public static final Creator<Component> CREATOR = new Creator<Component>() {
        @Override
        public Component createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Component(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Component[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Component[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
        parcel.writeString(name);
        parcel.writeDouble(latitude);
        parcel.writeDouble(longitude);
    }

    // Getters and Setters
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getLatitude() {
        return latitude;
    }

    public void setLatitude(double latitude) {
        this.latitude = latitude;
    }

    public double getLongitude() {
        return longitude;
    }

    public void setLongitude(double longitude) {
        this.longitude = longitude;
    }
}


The server's service file MyService.java:
package com.example.aidl_service;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.RemoteException;

public class MyService extends Service {

    private Component component;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return aidlBinder;
    }

    // AIDL Binder
    private final aidlInterface.Stub aidlBinder = new aidlInterface.Stub() {

        // Existing methods for location
        @Override
        public double[] getRandomLatLong() throws RemoteException {
            return new double[]{getRandomLatitude(), getRandomLongitude()};
        }

        @Override
        public void setNewLatLong(double lat, double lon) throws RemoteException {
            // Set new lat/long logic (already implemented)
        }

        // New AIDL methods to handle Component object
        @Override
        public Component getComponent() throws RemoteException {
            if (component == null) {
                // Generate a default component if null
                component = new Component("Default", getRandomLatitude(), getRandomLongitude());
            }
            return component;
        }

        @Override
        public void setComponent(Component component) throws RemoteException {
            MyService.this.component = component;
        }
    };

    // Generate random latitude
    private double getRandomLatitude() {
        return Math.random() * 180 - 90;
    }

    // Generate random longitude
    private double getRandomLongitude() {
        return Math.random() * 360 - 180;
    }
}


Finally the main activity of the server MainActivity.java:
package com.example.aidl_service;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static MainActivity instance;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        instance = this;
    }

    // Singleton pattern to access the activity instance
    public static MainActivity getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
}


Client App Code
The client app has the exact same aidl code and files as the server app, here is the main activity of the client app MainActivity.java:
package com.example.aidl_client;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.ServiceConnection;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.RemoteException;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.aidl_service.Component; // ERROR IN IMPORTING
import com.example.aidl_service.aidlInterface;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private TextView latDisplay, longDisplay, nameDisplay;
    private Button getComponentButton, setComponentButton;
    private Context mContext;

    private aidlInterface aidlInterfaceObject;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initialize the UI components
        mContext = this;
        latDisplay = findViewById(R.id.lat_display);
        longDisplay = findViewById(R.id.long_display);
        nameDisplay = findViewById(R.id.name_display); // New TextView for Component name
        getComponentButton = findViewById(R.id.get_location_button);
        setComponentButton = findViewById(R.id.set_location_button);

        // Set up button to get component
        getComponentButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                fetchComponent();
            }
        });

        // Set up button to send modified component
        setComponentButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                sendModifiedComponent();
            }
        });

        // Bind to the AIDL service
        bindAIDLService();
    }

    // Fetch component from the service
    private void fetchComponent() {
        if (aidlInterfaceObject != null) {
            try {
                // Fetch component object
                Component component = aidlInterfaceObject.getComponent();
                nameDisplay.setText("Component Name: " + component.getName());
                latDisplay.setText("Latitude: " + component.getLatitude());
                longDisplay.setText("Longitude: " + component.getLongitude());
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Error fetching component", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    // Send modified component to the service
    private void sendModifiedComponent() {
        if (aidlInterfaceObject != null) {
            try {
                // Create a new modified component
                Component component = new Component("Modified", 12.34, 56.78);
                aidlInterfaceObject.setComponent(component);

                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Component sent to service", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Error sending component", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    // Bind to the AIDL service
    private void bindAIDLService() {
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.aidl_service");
        bindService(convertImplicitIntentToExplicitIntent(intent, mContext), serviceConnection, BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    private ServiceConnection serviceConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
            aidlInterfaceObject = aidlInterface.Stub.asInterface(iBinder);
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
            aidlInterfaceObject = null;
        }
    };

   public Intent convertImplicitIntentToExplicitIntent(Intent implicitIntent, Context context) {
        PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfoList = packageManager.queryIntentServices(implicitIntent, 0);
        if (resolveInfoList == null || resolveInfoList.size() != 1) {
            return null;
        }
        ResolveInfo serviceInfo = resolveInfoList.get(0);
        ComponentName component = new ComponentName(serviceInfo.serviceInfo.packageName, serviceInfo.serviceInfo.name);
        Intent explicitIntent = new Intent(implicitIntent);
        explicitIntent.setComponent(component);
        return explicitIntent;
    }
}


I build and run the server app and it works fine, but I am unable to build the client app as I get the following error:
error: cannot find symbol
import com.example.aidl_service.Component;
                               ^
  symbol:   class Component
  location: package com.example.aidl_service

My understanding was that the Component class should be automatically generated in the client app when I run the server app, I am new to AIDL so there is probably something very trivial that I am missing. This is the complete code for the problem! Any help would be great! Thank you!
File directory for the Client AIDL:

